# Creating meta tags dynamically from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, metadata

I am developing a web application using `PHP-PDO-Mysql`. Here I have a product list page where the details of a particular product are shown. the details are fetched from DB. Now I want to dynamically set the meta description tag according to the selected products. I know it's not a suitable way to write PHP code inside `<head> tag`. What else can I do to get my meta desc tag dynamically?

I have found some tutorials and it doesn't help me. I have tried on my own. Please, anyone, help me to get my task accomplished.

Any answer will be appreciated

thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
$resPrdtDesc = $objScr->getCatDesc($catId);
    $totalDesc = $resPrdtDesc->getNumRows();  /*here is my db query to get details */
    if($totalDesc!=0) { 
        $metaDesc = $rowGetInfo['meta_desc']; // my meta tag desc from db
    }
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="<?$metaDesc?>" /> //here i echoed my meta tag db value
        <meta name="language" content="English" />
     </head>
```

but this is not working

Comment: What issue you are getting?

Comment: change <?$metaDesc?> to <?=$metaDesc?>

Comment: when i view page source it is not showing any content. But if I write the description directly it will be shown

Comment: I changed that too. still not working.

Comment: please print_r($metaDesc) and see you are getting from db or not.

Comment: hmm, depending on the php ini settings you either have to use `<?= $metaDesc ?>` or `<?php echo $metaDesc?>` If I am not mistaken the <?php echo is needed if php short tags are disabled in the php ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<?= $somevalue; ?>` to print value in content.

```
<meta name="description" content="<?$metaDesc?>" />
```

Change to

```
<meta name="description" content="<?=$metaDesc?>" />
```

Comment: That is the right answer, please check in source code if your php is interpreting properly or not.

Comment: @Aishwaryas, please see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847072/php-vs-php-echo-whats-the-difference-which-one-is-better-to-use

Comment: actually this application now i am working has been done by another developer. My task is to just add some features into it. The whole application is developed using this shortcut tag. I wonder why he created like that.!!

Comment: not working. Before this meta tag there is a title tag which is also populated from DB. It is working.